# MSMQ: Message Sent/Arrived time diff is occasionally high for unknown reasons

Tags: c#, queue, msmq

I am building a system that has several C# applications talking to one another via MSMQ. They are sending messages to queues, both on the local machine and on other machines on the network. 
Now, I have done the math, and 98.3% of the messages sent between every queue in the system arrive at their destination in <1 second (according to the sent/arrived times stored on the message).

The remaining 1.7%  of messages take between 1 and 60 seconds to reach their destination. In over 50,000 messages since the new year, it has never taken greater than exactly 60 seconds, which makes me think something is occasionally sleeping for a set amount of seconds before sending messages, but I cannot figure out what it could be. Id like to cut this unnecessary latency down as much as possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify? When you say "sending messages … between queues", do you mean App A reads a message from Queue ! and then sends a new message to Queue 2 for App B to read?

Comment: Edited for clarity to John Breakwell's question. @john, yes your assumption is correct

Comment: Looking at local-only traffic. If App A reads a message from local queue 1 and sends another to local queue 2, the MSMQ queue manager writes the new message straight to queue 2. There's no outgoing queue for this so, in theory, you shouldn't see any difference between sent and delivered time for local messages. The delivery is either instantaneous or fails with an error code. If you DO see a difference, then that's interesting.

Comment: For server-to-server network traffic, delays are caused by network connectivity issues or running out of threads for making connections. There are various timeouts that are used to handle these in a network-friendly manner. There are the various TCP/IP retry settings which affect all server networking. MSMQ also has a few, such as WaitTime. But you shouldn't need to change any settings if there are only a few clients.

Comment: That WaitTime setting sounds like exactly what i need! My main issue with this system is that we are using MSMQ in an environment where we need to try to keep latency as low as possible and msmq refusing to retry a connection for 60 seconds, just because, is too much. Ill post this as a solution if it fixes the problem

Comment: MSMQ was designed for guaranteed delivery, not necessarily for high speed throughput. Any wait times are arbitrary values set to prevent network flooding, etc. By all means, feel free to play with WaitTime to see if it allows you to have the throughput you want but that may be just a workaround for an issue somewhere else.